# Android Design Support Library 27.1.0 colors notificationbar grey

Tags: android, android-support-library

After updating to version 27.1.0, the pop-ups in my app have a grey notificationbar. Before the update, they were just blue, like all the other notificationbars. I haven't changed a thing in my code after updating. Is this a known issue?

[image]

Comment: Seems like several color definitions changed in this update. In my case, the menu drawables turn from grey to the accent color. That's probably related to Oreo's design tendence, which also turns toolbar title into accent.

Comment: Same issue for me when updating to 27.1.0.

Comment: Still don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered same problem and I used this in styles v21 and it works fine now

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```